# How to display only single Value OR single alternative value in ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to loop the entire array in ngFor and finally display **a single value**(where condition is met) or display **single alternative value**(where condition not met) excluding all other loop values. I mean I don't want to display any other values from loop except one.

```
 <div *ngFor="let arr1 of array1">                                                
    <div *ngFor="let arr2 of array2>                                                                                                              
       <input [value]="arr1.id==arr2.id?arr2.quantity:'0'>
     </div>   
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you please show array1 and array2?

Comment: I would suggest you to do this in your component file instead of template.

Comment: What is requirement, if condition not fulfilled.You have written to display a single value(where condition is met) or display single alternative value(where condition not met)? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Instead i would suggest you to do this operation in the component file:

```js
Public qty: number = 0;  // initialize with default value

Public getQty():number {
  this.qty = array1.filter((item, key) => { // filter the array1
     if(item.id === array2[key].id){    // check if item.id is found in array2
        return item;  // then return the item from array1.
     }
  })[0].quantity;
}

ngOnInit(){
   this.getQty(); // call it here or wherever it is required.
}
```

And in the template you can use the property:

```
<input [value]="qty">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `*ngIf` to solve this problem:

```
<div *ngFor="let arr1 of array1">                                                
   <div *ngFor="let arr2 of array2>                                                                                                              
      <input *ngIf="arr1.id==arr2.id" [value]="arr2.quantity">
   </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to display only single value(if condition is met-arr2.quantity,if not- '0') and IGNORE all other loop values.Like if array contains 10 values i want to display a single met value or a single alternative value and ingore all other 9 values.The problem is if condition not met it displaying alternative 9 times

Answer (score 0):

One solution is transform your array1, and add a new property "quantity2" using map

```
this.array1=this.array1.map(x=>{
       let unique=this.array2.find(a=>a.id==x.id);
       return
       {
          ...x,
          quantity2:unique? unique.quantity:0
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### .ts

```
public Value = '0';

for(let i=0; i<array1.length ;i++){
  for(let z=0;z<array2.length; z++){
   if(array1[i].id === array2[z].id){
   this.Value =  arr2[z].quantity;
    } else{
   this.Value =  '0';
}
  }
}
```

### .html

```
<input [value]="Value">
```

Comment: It seems it does not ignore other ngFor values.If array has length 10, it displays arr2.quantity once and input '0' for 9 times

Comment: What is requirement , if condition not fulfilled.You have written to display a single value(where condition is met) or display single alternative value(where condition not met)

Comment: i want to display only SINGLE value or SINGLE alternative value out of 10 loops say.